# how can achieve strechable layout from top vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, stretch

I have divided screen in two parts vertically , at top in one layout image view is there and at bottom layout text view is there. Now if suppose screen have 10 line,  where five line text is there and remaining five for image , then i have no issue . But suppose , six line text view now , then I want text should have to take one line from top and image view layout should take only in four line to fit. I have tried minHeight but not got result , here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_image"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d9d9d9">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_text"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/textview"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code does seem to work for me. Image occupies less space when the text is longer. Is this what you expect? See image: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/9920536?key=e5757f060fb0284592922f512964c168

Comment: Yes , its stretching from top in text view . But suppose , when i have bigger screen like moto then its not dividing screen in half mean equally. Please see image https://i.postimg.cc/HLZbj8qB/layout1.jpg

Comment: When i used ` android:adjustViewBounds="true" ` in image view then its dividing equally but for small screen text is hiding in bottom.